# Next.js Router.push() reloads page automatically

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js, next-router

Is there a way to execute a Router.push() without reloading the page using Next.js?

I am using a [...all].js main file for a page that based on the url renders different components, but i want to be able to move between them without triggering a full page reload - it is a multi-step form.

In other words, I want to be able to move between the steps of the form by also updating the URL from 'form/1' to 'form/2'

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Set option `shallow` to true to avoid page refresh

```
router.push('/?step=2', null, { shallow: true })
```

Comment: @FrancescoS Please set to answer. Thanks

Comment: Using null in `router.push('/?step=2', null, { shallow: true })` may lead to TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of null.
It's better to use undefined. `router.push('/?step=2', undefined, { shallow: true })`

Comment: Note that this probably only relevant if your page uses `getStaticProps`, `getServerSideProps` or `getInitialProps`.

Comment: For anyone looking the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing

shallow mitigated the flickering UI caused by reload for me.

Answer (score 7):

This page comes first on Next.js and 'page reloads'. To save others some time troubleshooting, consider this code:

```
router.push({query: {page: 1}}, undefined, { shallow: true });
```

It would seem there are some configurations of Next.JS that would make the page reload even if the query is the same as before, which is an easy way towards an infinite cycle of page reloads. Moreover, the browser would also reload unless you explicitly specify the pathname. I see this behavior on my server, but not on my laptop, both of which run Next.js 10.1.3. As far as I can tell, the only difference is there is no base URL set on my laptop, while the server does have a base URL. This remedies the problem:

```
let routerOpts = {page: 1};
if (!_.isEqual(routerOpts, router.query)) 
  router.push({pathname: router.pathname, query: routerOpts}, undefined, { shallow: true });
```

As far as I can tell, 'shallow' makes no difference and this works fine as well:

```
let routerOpts = {page: 1};
if (!_.isEqual(routerOpts, router.query)) router.push({pathname: router.pathname, query: routerOpts})
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page has more on router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

```
router.push(url, as, options)
```

url - The URL to navigate to

as - Optional decorator for the URL that will be shown in the browser. Before Next.js 9.5.3 this was used for dynamic routes, check our previous docs to see how it worked

options - Optional object with the following configuration options:

shallow: Update the path of the current page without rerunning getStaticProps, getServerSideProps or getInitialProps. Defaults to false

You don't need to use router.push for external URLs. window.location is better suited for those cases

Answer (score 0):

I also encounted the above issue, where actually adding `{shallow: true}` was not good a enough solution.

Depending on the events you have on your form input elements such as: `onKeyUp` upon hitting the enter key, for example, You may also need to call `event.preventDefault()` to keep the form from reloading the page and allow `router.push()` to do it's thing. Yeah, D'oh!  ;}

```
const search = (e) => {
   if ( event.key === 'Enter' && event.target.value) {
      event.preventDefault();
      router.push(`/foo?q=${event.target.value}`, undefined, { shallow: true })
   }
}

return(
  <input 
    ... 
    onKeyPress={search} 
  />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My use case is to keep record on which tab panel clicks and return to the correct tab panel context when user is coming back from a sub page. I could not get `router.push` to work without triggering reload / rerender and consuming the API. In my case, `shallow` didn't have any difference (Next.js v12).

I ended up using browser's built-in `history`:

```
const historyPushTab = (tab) =>
  window.history.pushState({ tab }, '', `/?tab=${tab}`);
```

Now, using browser's back button the app will land on the correct tab panel now if user comes back from a sub page. For example, going back from `/sub-page` to `/?tab=4` works like intended.

**BUT** as a drawback Next.js **won't recognize** browser's back button presses on other tabs **if the user is on the same page** (`/?tab=3` to `/?tab=1`). I'm fine with that.