Next.js: reload current api
Is there a way to reload current api or current route without reloading the page using Next.js?
I attempted to use router.push(router.pathname) to refresh the current API, but it did not succeed.
I'm seeking a method to reload the current API without refreshing the entire page or browser.

did you check this Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61130038/next-js-router-push-reloads-page-automatically?rq=2
** router.push('/', null, { shallow: true }) **
It might be what you are looking for

I already checked it, didn't work for me
